# Pushing to Github using Personal Access Token not working

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have been attempting to push to gh using a generated personal access token from my shell terminal. It worked only once after I spammed `git --set-upstream origin push master` but it's not pushing commits anymore. I can still clone repos.

I have also edited the git config file but it keeps asking for a password. Whenever I use the token, it throws this error:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/kurosakiaduma/alx-pre_course.git/'
```

Here are my **remotes**:

```
origin  https://kurosakiaduma:xxx@github.com/kurosakiaduma/alx-pre_course.git (fetch)
origin  https://kurosakiaduma:xxx@github.com/kurosakiaduma/alx-pre_course.git (push)
```

Where could I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first your `git config --global credential.helper` value.

If it is `xxx` (like 'manager' or 'manager-core'), check what is stored for github.com

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx get
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=kurosakiaduma" | git credential-xxx get
```

(replace `xxx` by the value returned by `git config --global credential.helper`)

That way, you will know if a password (instead of a token) was stored/ cached in the credential helper.

If the wrong value is stored, you can overwrite it with:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=kurosakiaduma\npassword=ghp_yourToken" | git credential-xxx store
```

Comment: Quick note: on my Windows machine, `git-credential-manager-core get` with the hyphen after `git` does not work (error: command not found), but `git credential-manager-core get` with a space after `git` works properly.

Comment: Thanks to you both! The issue was it was still using my actual github password in the cache. I've had to regenerate the token and authenticate it all over again. Now, `printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=kurosakiaduma" | git credential-manager-core get` returns my username and the token.